# mySQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

```
 INSERT into error_log 
   (id_user, id_error, severity, date) 
 VALUES 
   ('93, '1', '6', '1285886665')
```

Throwing

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1', '6', '1285886794')' at line 4
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `error_log` (
  `id` int(25) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_user` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `id_error` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `severity` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: `('93,` misses a closing quote, consider an editor with SQL highlighting, then you'd have spotted it immediately.

Comment: also wanna throw out there that technically date is a reserved word.  Normally mysql will yell at you for using reserved words as column names unless you wrap it in backtics, but date is one of the exceptions.  But you never know if that might change in the future and be required, and it's just bad practice in general to name columns reserved words, so you might wanna change that column name to something else, like error_date or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT into error_log 
 (id_user, id_error, severity, `date`) 
VALUES 
 (93, 1, 6, '1285886665')
```

The issue was an unclosed single quote on the value for `id_user`.
Text values need to be enclosed in single quotes, like for the `date` column.  But INTegers don't need to be wrapped in single quotes, though MySQL will implicitly convert the data type to whatever the column is... or it will throw an error.